# Is a function call parameter always a new object?

Tags: c++, copy, parameter-passing

I read that:

> In Java, all parameters are passed by value. In C++, a parameter can
>   be passed by:
>
> ```
> value,
> reference, or
> const-reference
> ```

However, if I pass a pointer to a function and in that function I change the pointer, this will not change the object, whose identifier was used to specify it as a parameter, it will only change the pointer passed into the function.

That actually means that technically, in C++ everything is PASSED BY VALUE AS A COPY, the difference is that this copied value can be used as a memory address (pointer or reference), so if I want to modify an existing pointer passed as a function parameter I must pass the value of its memory address and not the value of the memory address, held by that pointer.

**So is the assumptions that every function parameter is a new copy derived from an existing object created specifically to serve as a parameter in a single particular call and NEVER an actual pre-existing object a correct one?**

Comment: Yes, this is technically true. Semantically, passing a reference (as in `int&`) could be considered different. But the actual code executed on the CPU is still pushing a memory address which cannot be changed.

Comment: Pass by reference is very different semantically than passing a pointer by value. Passing a pointer by value you need to explicitly take the address of something to get a pointer to pass; and inside the function you need to dereference it to perform operations on the thing pointed to. With passing by reference you don't do either of these things -- you pass something as if passing by value, and inside the function you operate on the parameter as if operating on a value. Don't confound these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Java, all parameters are passed by value.

This is somewhat misleading, because when object references are passed by value, and the objects support mutation, the caller can change the object passed in, effectively making it look like a pass by reference.

> That actually means that technically, in C++ everything is PASSED BY VALUE AS A COPY, the difference is that this copied value can be used as a memory address (pointer or reference), so if I want to modify an existing pointer passed as a function parameter I must pass the value of its memory address and not the value of the memory address, held by that pointer.

This assessment is correct. Passing by pointer and passing by reference still creates a copy of something in the space of the function being called, at least logically:

- When an object is passed by value, a copy of the object itself is created
- When an object is passed by pointer, a copy of the pointer is created
- When an object is passed by reference, a copy of the reference is created

In short, whatever is passed to the caller, is passed by value. Sometimes, that passed value can be used to modify the original object.

When you consider optimization and inlining, things start getting messier: it is possible that no copy of your pointer or the reference is created, but the overall logic remains the same.

Comment: "effectively making it look like a pass by reference." NO. There is a big difference.

Comment: @newacct Mind being more specific? I think I was pretty specific in what sense it makes it look like a pass by ref, so bluntly saying "NO" doesn't quite do it justice, does it?

Comment: Pass by value and Pass by reference have very specific semantic meanings dealing with the variable passed. It has nothing to do with the object pointed to by the variable if it's a pointer. Java has only pass-by-value. Trying to muddy over the difference is the reason why so many people are confused about this.

Comment: @newacct The biggest reason some people are confused about this is that in Java an object reference is passed by value. There is absolutely nothing wrong in pointing out similarities to passing by reference in this arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

> That actually means that technically, in C++ everything is PASSED BY VALUE AS A COPY, the difference is that this copied value can be used as a memory address (pointer or reference)

Yes, your assumption technically is right, for almost all common programming languages. Why? 
You should note that *pass by reference* **is a software abstraction**. What the CPU really does (Of course this depends on the function call convention, I'm simplifying things) is to copy the data into registers.

To simulate that you are working with the same value, what you do (And what most common languages do) is to pass the memory address of the original data, in other words, a pointer. 
Thats what C does to simulate pass by reference, thats what C++ does (References are really pointers), and thats what Java does.

Answer (score 0):

What is passed to a function is indeed a unique object. However, if we have `object X`, and we take make a reference `object& Y = X;`, and then `object& Z = X;`, then we have three "objects" - `X` which is of type `object`, and `Y` and `Z` which are of the type reference to `object`. There is still only one "real" instance of `object` - `Y` and `Z` are both referencing the same `X`.

Likewise, if we pass a reference to a function:

```
void func(object& R)
{
  ...
}
```

with

```
func(X);
```

the function will receive an object that is a reference to `X` - which makes the function appear as if it's actually modifying `X`, since that is how references work - the actual value of a reference is something that refers to the original object.

What I'm trying to say is that "everything passed into a function is a unique object, but it may be referring to the same original object in case of a reference".

In C++, pointers and references are very similar, aside from two things:
 1. A reference can only be initialized to a particular object once - and it can only be created in such a way that it actually refers to an object, you can't have a reference that refers to "nothing" or "isn't set yet" [you can however have "stale" references, where the object that it originally referred to no longer exists].
 2. References uses the same syntax as the basic object, e.g. `r.member = 42;`, where pointers use `*p` or `p->member = 42;` to "get" to the content of the object.

[Yes, it's entirely possible, within the C++ specification to define a compiler where pointers and references are "not the same thing internally", but so far I've never seen one]